# How to deploy html5 boilerplate publish folder ( probably using git-ftp )

Tags: web-deployment, html5boilerplate, git-ftp

I am still searching for a good development -> deployment workflow (mostly for smaller websites) using html5 boilerplate + build script, gitHub, and probably git-ftp.

The problem is I can’t figure out a cool way of how to deploy the publish folder of html5 boilerplate to my webserver (where I normally have no ssh access)

How do you do it?

What if the website uses a CMS like redaxo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the syncroot option of git-ftp to specify the directory to sync from as if it were the git project root path. In .git/config under [git-ftp] add

```
syncroot = publish/
```

Answer (score 0):

Just **use** git-ftp in the "publish" folder:

1. Make a git repository out of the "publish" folder

   ```
   cd publish
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "This is now a git repo"
   ```
2. Configure git-ftp in publish/.git/config, then use:

   ```
   git ftp init
   ```